# Anchor Point Jumps Instead Of Smooth Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason when i click my logo image which is the same anchor point link as 'Home' on my Nav Menu it jumps instead of smooth scrolling like 'Home' does when it's clicked.

Does anyone know why this is happening & how do i go about correcting this? Thanks in advance :)

```
  <!-- LOGO -->
    <div class="logo pull-left">
        <a href="#home"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <!-- //LOGO -->


    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="pull-right">
        <nav class="navmenu center">
            <ul>
                <li class="first active scroll_btn"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#projects">Products</a></li>
                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                <li class="scroll_btn last"><a href="#contacts">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- //MENU -->
```

Comment: This doesn't work without a JS. The problem is in your JS.

Comment: without knowing your JS I guess you should add 'scroll_btn' as class to your logo surrounding div. If this does not work, you need to edit your js not only to handle li.scroll_btn, but all scroll_btn or also div.scroll_btn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your existing ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".logo a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
      scrollLeft: 0
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your a god amongst men Praveen! Once again you have solved my problem. Many thanks ;-)

Comment: It would be my pleasure! DONE ;-)